# Android Media Player Auto Restart

Tags: android, refresh, android-mediaplayer, media, restart

For some reason on every other phone I've tested the app on the music does not restart after you change views and come back. It works perfectly on my phone but two of my testers and my daughter tablet do the same. When you open the Phone pad or anything that makes the music stop cuts the music off (Planned) but when you close the email/phone screen the music does not restart (For them) it works fine for me.

How can I ensure the the music will restart after you make a call, or send an email and come back to the main view?

Here is my Main Java:

```
                package w1r.wilder1radio;

                import android.annotation.TargetApi;
                import android.app.Activity;
                import android.app.AlertDialog;

                import android.content.DialogInterface;
                import android.content.Intent;

                import android.media.AudioManager;
                import android.media.MediaPlayer;
                import android.net.Uri;

                import android.os.Build;
                import android.os.Bundle;


                import android.util.Log;

                import android.view.View;

                import android.webkit.WebView;
                import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
                import android.widget.Button;

                import android.widget.Toast;

                import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;



                public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {


                MediaPlayer mp;

                //Button Names
                Button btncall;
                Button btnqrcode;
                Button btnemail;
                Button btnshare;


                Button navfacebook;
                Button navtwitter;
                Button navgoogleplus;


                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {


                if (!mp.isPlaying())
                if ((mp != null)) {

                    mp.start();
                }

                }

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(this);
                AppRater.app_launched(this);


                //Now Playing WebView
                WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
                view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                String url2 = "http://markesswilder.com/w1rnowplaying.html";
                view.loadUrl(url2);


                //Media Player

                try {

                mp = new MediaPlayer();
                String url = "http://75.126.73.136:8042/;";
                mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mp.setDataSource(url);
                mp.prepareAsync();
                mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);

                if (mp!=null) {
                    initMediaPlayer();
                } else if (!mp.isPlaying()) mp.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("ExceptionOnCreate:", e.getMessage());

                e.getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Please check your WiFi/or Carrier Service and try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


                //Button id

                btncall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncall);
                btnqrcode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnqrcode);
                btnemail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnemail);
                btnshare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnshare);

                //Menu Buttons

                navfacebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.navfacebook);
                navtwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.navtwitter);
                navgoogleplus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.navgoogleplus);


                //Button Clicks

                btncall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    sendToCall();

                }
                });


                btnqrcode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    sendToQrCode();

                }
                });


                btnemail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    goToEmail();


                }

                });


                btnshare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    goToShare();


                }

                });


                navfacebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    sendToNavFaceBook();


                }


                });


                navtwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  sendToNavTwitter();


                }


                }

                );


                navgoogleplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 sendToNavGooglePlus();


                }


                }

                );

                }

                //???
                private void initMediaPlayer() {

                }

                //Button Clicks Handlers

                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                protected void sendToCall() {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
                builder1.setIcon(R.drawable.shoutoutslogo);
                builder1.setTitle("Call Us");
                builder1.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                builder1.setCancelable(false);
                builder1.setMessage("Want to hear your voice on our station? " +
                    "Send us your name and where you're calling from. If we like it we'll put it on the air. " +
                    "Just remember to finish with - Wilder1Radio Go Ahead GET WILD!");
                builder1.setPositiveButton("I'M READY TO SHOUT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if user pressed "yes", then open phone pad
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+1 614-383-9939"));
                    startActivity(callIntent);


                }
                });
                builder1.setNegativeButton("NOT READY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if user selects "No", cancel this dialog and continue with the app
                    dialog.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Continue to enjoy the music.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder1.create();
                alert.show();
                }


                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                protected void sendToQrCode() {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
                builder2.setIcon(R.drawable.qrwilder1radio);
                builder2.setTitle("Scan Me");
                builder2.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                builder2.setCancelable(false);
                builder2.setMessage("Easily share this App with all your Android friends. " +
                    "Help us support Independent, Soul Music and Artists by simply having others scan this bar-code with any Android scan program and download this app. " +
                    "Share the music and share your love for independent artists around the world.");

                builder2.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if user selects "No", cancel this dialog and continue with the app
                    dialog.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Thank you for sharing the Music.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder2.create();
                alert.show();
                }


                protected void goToEmail() {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("message/rfc822");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"markessw@gmail.com"});
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "I LOVE THIS STATION!!!");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                }


                protected void goToShare() {
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=w1r.wilder1radio";
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "You'll Love This App!!!");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));



                }


                //top nav buttons

                protected void sendToNavFaceBook() {
                String url = "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Wilder1Radio/125698310843952";
                Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                in.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(in);


                }

                protected void sendToNavTwitter() {
                String url = "https://twitter.com/Wilder1Radio";
                Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                in.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(in);
                mp.pause();

                }

                protected void sendToNavGooglePlus() {
                String url = "https://plus.google.com/u/0/107138907547512605174";
                Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                in.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(in);



                }

                //Close App Alert

                @Override
                public void onBackPressed() {
                //Opens alert message when back button is pressed when in main view
                backButtonControl();
                }

                public void backButtonControl() {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);
                //Dialog Title
                alertDialog.setTitle("Closing W1R App");
                //Dialog Message
                alertDialog.setMessage("Ready to go off the air?");
                //Add Icon to Dialog
                alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.w1ricon);
                //"Yes" Button
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //If YES, close app completely
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                //"NO" Button
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //If NO, show toast and close alert only
                            dialog.cancel();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Thank you for your support", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                //Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();
                }


                @Override
                public void onResume() {
                super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
                // Play again, tough be carefull in the beggining for null pointers
                }

                @Override
                public void onPause() {
                super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
                // Stop playing, we are paused. Phone call, ...
                }

                @Override
                protected void onStop() {
                super.onDestroy();
                if(mp!=null){
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    mp.stop();
                }
                mp.release();
                mp = null;
                }

                }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods you need to override

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
   // Play again, tough be carefull in the beggining for null pointers
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
    // Stop playing, we are paused. Phone call, ...
}
```

Comment: I will try that now thank you. Do I add these in addition to everything else or removing something? I know my code is crazy I'm just learning so I do appreciate the help thanks

Comment: Okay I added the code just before the public void onStop Override and it's doing the same thing to them. It's hard for me to test because it works fine for me so I'm really not sure what it is. Two Android phones and an Android Tablet all momentarily freeze, and then no music after clicking one of the buttons that changes the view.

Comment: Also after that when you hit the backpress button to close they get an error saying unexpected something - ok,(sorry I don't remember.) I'm not sure why its working for me but not the others. Thank you again.

Comment: Any other suggestions? I'm not getting any errors on my end so I don't know where to look.

Comment: Ok I just got more feedback. Even if they don't change the view (They just open the app and backpress to pull up the close alert box (onBackPressed)  they get an error. "Unfortunately Wilder1Radio has stopped".

Comment: Ok I've updated the code, I went through it line by line and have gotten the close error to stop coming up when you shut the app down. The big issue still remains that when you click the button to make a phone call or send an email (Leaving the main view) and the player/music stops (as it should) when you onBackPressed back to the main activity  the music/stream/media player does not restart. And because this happens on every other phone I have had people test it on BUT MINE (it works as it should on my phone) I don't have any errors to check. Any Idea what it could be going by my code?

Comment: I see your updated version, but you have to tell the mediaplayer to pause and play. I haven't done that in my code, I just left you the comment.

Comment: Ok so in the button clicks add the pause or play and then the override will handle the rest? I think I understand I will try that now.

Comment: Ok I won't pretend to know more than I know. I'm not sure how to do that with the way I have set things up. I probably would have done it differently if I was experiencing the problems but like I said on my phone it works correctly. But I can't put this on the market with hidden issues. Now when I add the pause to the onclick the music does not restart for any button when I close that view. I just need it to pause when you leave the main view via opening email, text, make a call. And then when you use the back button to come back the music starts again. Thanks